# GTD note-taking software tool that works with Outlook

Tags: project-management, note-taking, outlook

I am looking for a tool that allows me to take notes - e.g., meeting notes, clips from web, even (parts of) email messages - as well as support the GTD methodology. Bare minimum, it should allow

1. tagging specific notes, actions or follow-up items with context such as person(s) to discuss with or events at which to follow-up or things to do at work/home etc.,
2. set due-dates and priorities,
3. generate views of items based on context or priority or due-date.

Most importantly it should interoperate nicely with Outlook. Send Outlook message as a to-do item or to the GTD Inbox to process. It'd be a bonus if it can recognize Outlook contacts or have a mobile app. Preferably a free/open-source app or at least an open data format that is stored locally (must not sync automatically to cloud).